# What is the equivalent of FirstSibling in .NET XMLNode?

Tags: vb.net, xmlnode

I have a dynamic number of `<image>` elements in an xml doc. When I reach the end of those elements I was to set the attribute on the first of these siblings to true again.

How do I get FirstSibling or something like that?

Non-Dynamic but works
`parentNode.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.Attributes(0).Value = "true"`

XML:

```
<imageConfig>
  <image active="false">
    <pathName>/Images/123.jpg</pathName>
    <imageStartTime>Mon Dec 29 09:34:35 EST 2014</imageStartTime>
  </image>
  <image active="false">
    <pathName>/Images/1234.jpg</pathName>
    <imageStartTime>Mon Dec 29 09:34:35 EST 2014</imageStartTime>
  </image>
  <image active="false">
    <pathName>/Images/12345.jpg</pathName>
    <imageStartTime>Mon Dec 29 09:34:35 EST 2014</imageStartTime>
  </image>
  <image active="false">
    <pathName>/Images/123456.jpg</pathName>
    <imageStartTime>Mon Dec 29 09:34:35 EST 2014</imageStartTime>
  </image>
  <image active="true">
    <pathName>/Images/1234567.jpg</pathName>
    <imageStartTime>Mon Dec 29 09:34:35 EST 2014</imageStartTime>
  </image>
</imageConfig>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XPath with the `preceding-sibling` axis:

```
Dim firstSibling As XmlNode = parentNode.SelectNodes("preceding-sibling::*")(0)
```

See [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: should firstSibling.Attributes(0).Value = '' work at this point?

Comment: @JoJo, Yes. I assume so.

Comment: `Dim firstSibling As XmlNode` is required

Comment: Sorry, I'm writing mainly C#. Updated.